# jquery select menu box not showing up

Tags: jquery

my problem is i can not get select menu in my page to show up time menu list. i tried changing the code. still can not get it to work. if i remove script link 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js then the select menu shows up. then my paypal store pages item links stop working then. is there anything i can do get it all to work than you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As

```
    <div id="contactForms">
        <div class="container">

                    <label>Options:</label>
                    <select name="option" id="option" data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true" >
                        <option selected="selected">T</option>
                        <option>irs</option>
                    </select>

                    <label for="date">Select a Date: </label>
                    <input name="date" type="date" id="date" />

                    <label>Select a Time:</label>
                    <select name="time" id="time">
                        <option selected="selected">8.30</option>
                        <option>9:00</option>
                        <option>9:30</option>
                    </select>

                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="names" id="names" required>

                    <label>Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address">

                    <label>Town:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="town" id="town">



                <label>D:</label>
                <p>We</p>
                <select name="drop" id="drop">
                    <option selected="selected">No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                </select>

                <label>Col:</label>
                <p>Too</p>
                <select name="collection" id="collection">
                    <option selected="selected">No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                </select>

                <p>
                    <label>Lo:</label>
                <p>Ca</p>
                <select name="loan" id="loan">
                    <option selected="selected">No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <br>
                <p class="full">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </p>
    </div>
    </head>
</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1AA5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting you whole code, on head tags? try to move the code into

```
 <body></body>
```

body tags

Comment: hi that didnt fix the problem plus i am getting tiny submit button and with no style. no styling any of my pages. something is not allowing my css style to work. can you please help.

Comment: First check that, your code is in proper order, <html><head></head><body></body></html>, if it is in order then please upload your code so i can help you.